# EpiServer - GetPartialVirtualPath is called several times

Tags: routes, episerver, episerver-7

I have a custom implementation of the `IPartialRouter` with the method `GetPartialVirtualPath`. So it looks like

```
public class MyCustomPartialRouter : IPartialRouter<PageType, ModelType>
{
    public PartialRouteData GetPartialVirtualPath(ModelType article, string language, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        //Some code here...
    }

    public object RoutePartial(PageType content, SegmentContext segmentContext)
    {
        //... and here
    }
}
```

In another place I make a call of `UrlResolver.GetVirtualPathForNonContent` method inside the extentsion-method:

```
public static string GetUrl(this UrlResolver urlResolver, object partialRoutedObject)
    {
        var language = ContentLanguage.PreferredCulture.Name;
        var virtualPath = urlResolver.GetVirtualPathForNonContent(partialRoutedObject, language, new VirtualPathArguments());

        return virtualPath.GetUrl();
    }
```

After that method `GetPartialVirtualPath` is called 7 times... in another project with the same logic I have the same behavior.

Have you any idea why that might be?

Comment: Is it the same `partialRoutedObject` every time?

Comment: @TedNyberg `GetPartialVirtualPath` called with the same model all of these 7 call

Comment: I would suggest looking at the call stack to figure out where/when it gets invoked.

Comment: @TedNyberg every time it calls from this line `var virtualPath = urlResolver.GetVirtualPathForNonContent(partialRoutedObject, language, new VirtualPathArguments());`